# React Router ALL LINK IS WORKING FINE EXPECT to="/" is not working which i want to access another path="/"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**its app js main file**
**this code i try**
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
return (






)

```
**Here iS LINKS all link is working fine but not last one**
**Cant access last link when i click on that link it show blankk display and giving any 
  error**

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import MenuIcon from "../Images/menu.png";
     

    <div>
      <header>
      <Link to="/userhome"  style={style}>
          <span className="Title">DIARY NOTE</span>
          </Link>
          <nav>
            <ul >
              <Link to="/userhome"  style={style}>
              <li  className="listItems">HOME</li>
              </Link>``
              <Link to="/previousnote" style={style}>
              <li   className="listItems">PREVIOUS NOTE</li>
              </Link>
               **This link is not working**
              <Link to="/" style={style}>
              <li className="LogOutBtn" className="listItems">LOG OUT</li>
              </Link>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <img src={MenuIcon} className="menuIcon" />
          </header>
      </div>
```

Comment: can you show us your Router component?

Comment: its all done but can you help me about how can i set a url into react link..Like now when i passing url into link of react it show first "https//localhost:3000/www.facebook.com" so can you help into this to me?

Comment: `import {Link} from "react-router-dom"` and `<Link to="/path/to/page1">Go to Page 1</Link>`

Comment: Thanks You Ajeet but now what if i want to give Facebook or Linkdin link into <Link>

Comment: I think you will have to use `<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">External Site</a>`. I think you can't go to the external site using `Link` from react router.